# How to update data into multilayer structure on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I want to embedding a new document of comment into it's parent's comment.

Here is a document of a blog post on MongoDB.

```
{ '_id': 1,
  'title': xxx,
  'content': xxx,
  'comments': [
          {
                'id': 1,
                'author': xxx,
                'content':xxx
          },
          {
                'id': 2,
                'author': xxx,
                'content':xxx
          }
  ]
}
```

I want to add a new comment that it's parent's comment id is 1.

How can I do like below:

```
'comments': [
          {
                'id': 1,
                'author': xxx,
                'content':xxx
                'comments':[
                        {
                              'id':3,
                              'author': xxx,
                              'content':xxx
                        }
                ]
          },
          {
                'id': 2,
                'author': xxx,
                'content':xxx
          }
  ]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows :

```
db.collection.update({"_id" : 1, "comments.id" : 1},{$push : {"comments.$.comments" : {id : 3, author : "xxx", content:"xxx"}}})
```

Comment: I have a little confused about the 'comments.$.comments'. What is the effect of the '$'?

Comment: @user2742381: The `$` is the [positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/). It acts as a placeholder for the first matching array element for each document in a query (so in this case, the first element of the array where `comments.id` is `1`).